# PHP Sessions not saving in Safari on Mac nor iOS, but on localhost

Tags: php, session, safari, session-cookies

I have a problem with sessions in PHP as it seems that the Safari browser **is not saving session-content** to access on other page. Same problem on ios-system. But it works on Android and other browsers on Mac such as Opera, Chrome and Firefox. 
Safari allows cookies for every page I visit and it worked when working with localhost/Apache server through Xampp.

First: p1.php

```
    <?php
session_start();

echo 'Welcome to Page #1';

$_SESSION['color'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal'] = 'Spider';
$_SESSION['time'] = time();

echo '<p>If session cookie accepted</p>';
echo '<br /><a href="p2.php">Page 2</a>';

echo '<p> Or passing session_id</p>';
echo '<br /><a href="p2.php?' . SID . '">Page 2</a>';
?>
```

Page 2 p2.php

```
    <?php
session_start();

echo 'Welcome to Page #2<br />';

echo $_SESSION['color'];  // green
echo $_SESSION['animal'];   // spider
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);

 '<br /><a href="p1.php">Page 1</a>';
?>
```

It's a mysterious problem to me and I don't feel well making websites if the support for Safari doesn't work. 
Does anybody have an idea?

UPDATE: Also asked a friend of mine on the other side of the world. He reproduced it and got the same problem.

UPDATE: I tried something. Used the code on PHP Fiddle. Same problem. Then I used C9.io and it worked. Both, as you know, let you work in the browser and I used Safari.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? What error do you get?

Comment: Is no session data being saved at all? Or is it just the `echo date()` part that isn't working?

Comment: There's no data being saved. It's always empty. Even faced that, when I start a session and want to save a session_id, the ID is changing every time as it has to be newly created.

Comment: @bub: removed them and no change at all.

Answer (score -1):

Add ob_clean() the before session start.

Let me know if not working

Comment: Unfortunately no success. Same result.